# Procedure converting decimals to rationals.

Tags: rational-numbers, decimal-expansion

Suppose I have been given a rational number in decimal format (since decimals of rationals repeat, finite precision presentation suffices), what is the most effective way to write it in form of ratio of integers $P/Q$?

I can think of checking if decimal is greater than $1$. If so, truncate decimal portion and invert it. This will again be decimal. So truncate and invert and repeat. Procedure should terminate. Group all terms in expansion to get needed ratio $P/Q$. Is there a better procedure to obtain the needed conversion?

Comment: How do you measure _effective_? The most simple procedure is multiplying by the smallest power of 10 so that the product is an integer, then reduce to lowest terms. This would be exact. Or do you want approximations with restricted $P,Q$?

Comment: No I am interested in bit complexity.

Comment: This [thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049699/how-to-extract-fraction-from-a-floating-point-number) may help.